# Div breaks jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery accordion that breaks when I need to place a div-tag in one of the sliding open areas.. How do I get around this? I need to put a div-tag since I cannot make a nice box out of a span-tag. Anyone knows a way around this??

Please see my demo here to see where it breaks :(

http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/

Comment: Could it have something to do with using block elements inside paragraphs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change this:

```
$(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow")
       .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
```

to:

```
$(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow")
       .siblings("div:visible").slideUp("slow");
```

and the CSS:

```
.accordion2 > div {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    /* etc... */
```

It makes more sense to use a `DIV` instead of `P` if you want to put other elements inside the expandable content: http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/13/

Or just use inline elements inside the `P` tag and style them to `display:block;`, but it doesn’t make semantic sense to me.

Comment: How do I change from only having <div> to have it specified as its own class for example I want the expandable accordion to start when I enter <div class="expandable"> instead of only <div> ? I hope you understand my question and thanks for help

Comment: @MarcusSilverman your problem has already been solved and you accepted another answer. If you have another question, create a new post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit lame, but you can use a `span` and just set it to `display: block`. Then it's essentially a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/5/

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you put it in a span and style the span as a nice box with display block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a span-tag. All you need to do is add the following styling for your span-tag class in the css

```
.whatever {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a different way to try your accordion without messing around with CSS

Get your `HTML` done as follows;

```
<div id='accordion'>
 <h3>Title of the view</h3>
 <div>
  all the stuff you want to do here
 </div>
 <h3>Title of the view</h3>
 <div>
  all the stuff you want to do here
 </div>
</div>
```

and make your script file as

```
 $('#accordion').accordion({ active: 0 });
```

For more info: visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/21/ and changed your `p` tags to `div` tags since it allows the most tag nesting.

As a general rule, a `div` tag cannot be inside of a `p` tag since it will cause the `p` tag to close itself.

Comment: Thanks a million. How do I change from only having <div> to have it specified as its own class for example I want the expandable accordion to start when I enter <div class="expandable"> instead of only <div> ? I hope you understand my question and thanks for help

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  Is it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zRqYM/22/?  Basically only `<div class="expandable">` will show/hide and all regular divs will not.

Comment: Thanks @simonleojung, that is a big help!!